# Parse - Object does not appear in my relation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, parse-platform, relation, favorites

I'm using the anonymous user feature of Parse so that each user can create a "Favorite" list and not have to create an account on the app.

When a user is on an item detail page there will be a "Star" image and when selected that object should be added to their Favorite List, which will be a table on another UIViewController.

Here's my code when adding to favorites:

```
PFQuery * query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"ClassA"];
[query whereKey:@"item_name" equalTo:self.itemLabel.text];
[query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }
    else
    {
        PFUser * user = [PFUser currentUser];

        self.favRelation = [user relationforKey:@"favorite"];

        [self.favRelation addObject:object];

        [user saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
            if (error)
            {
                NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"Yay!!");
            }
        }];


    }
}];
```

When this code runs, the Relation was added to my User table in Parse, but when I select "View Relations", I just see the User again.

Am I over looking something or missing something?

Comment: You have to fire the query again for getting the user you have added, or you have to refresh the table. Dont have iphone exp so i might be wrong. But its looking like you are missing to refresh the table.

Comment: The issues I am having right now is getting the objects added to the Relation table in Parse. That is what the code example above is. I'm able to NSLog the object and confirm it is the correct one, but when I tap on "View Relations", it just shows me the Users again and not the object.